# Codigniter 4, retrieve from MySQL, read as JSON and display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I have the following table : `z_table`

```
Field   Type            Null    Key     Default     Extra

id      int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment

name    varchar(128)    NO              NULL
```

**My Model:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Z_model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $table = 'z_table';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function get_data($q)
    {
        $query = $this->connect->query($q);
        $data = array();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            echo $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**My Controller :**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Z extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {        
        $data['z'] = $this->db->get('z_table')->result_array();
        
        $this->load->view('z/index', $data);
        
    } //index

    public function fetch()
    {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM z_table ORDER BY id DESC";
        $this->load->model('z_model');
        $data = $this->z_model->get_data($q);
        return JSON_encode($data);       
    } //fetch
}
```

**My Ajax :**

```
    function ajaxRequest(params) {
        var action = "view";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>z/fetch",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: action
            },
            success: function(items) {
                console.log(items);
                params.success({
                    rows: items,
                    records: JSON.parse(items)
                }, null);
            },
            error: function(er) {
                console.log("error", er);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I want to query z_table and store it as JSON then display it in view.
I think there is something not right in my ajax, I don't know what it is and how to fix it.

**The browser console says :**

```
    jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/proj/z/fetch 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajaxRequest @   zakat:528
calculateObjectValue    @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
value   @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
value   @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
value   @   bootstrap-table-print.min.js:10
(anonymous) @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
each    @   jquery.min.js:2
i.default.fn.bootstrapTable @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
(anonymous) @   bootstrap-table.min.js:10
e   @   jquery.min.js:2
t   @   jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js:2
c   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
fire    @   jquery.min.js:2
c   @   jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js:2
ready   @   jquery.min.js:2
B   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

Please advise.

Comment: Turn on errors in your PHP script by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to identify the issue. Also in your model rather than printing the array, you should return it as `return $data;`

Comment: I changed the Model :


class Z_model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $table = 'z_table';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function get_data($q)
    {
        $query = $this->connect->query($q);
        $data = array();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Same error. I dont know how to add the php error line _/\_

Comment: My Ajax seems never come into success: function(items)

Comment: ` url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>z/fetch"` check if URL is formed correctly or not. You will have to debug step by step and identify the issue. console.log the URL and hit in the browser to see if it's going to your controller's `fetch` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the model to :

```
public function get_data($q)
{
$data = $this->db->get('tab_data');
return $data->result();     
}
```

It should not be echo-ed. Resolved.